# Check if username exist/activated in database using MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' AND activate='0'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'Account not activated.';
}
```

I'm new to MYSQLi and I need help on how do I show an error if the user enter a wrong username and its not activated. So far I got the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='".$username."' AND activate='0'");

  if ($result->num_rows) {
echo "you are activated !!";
                          } 

   else
  {
  // do what u like here if not activated
    }
```

Comment: This is really UGLY, you should use prepared statements (even if the OP doesn't, you should suggest a better approach): http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php. AND you should NEVER use `SELECT *` (type the needed fields explicitly)!